# FFmpeg insert loop frame and audio within a video

Tags: loops, ffmpeg, trim

I have a video, that I would like to freeze frame at 32s for 30s, and also loop audio from section 30-32s for those 30s.  My current video is 40s long in total.
I've got it mostly to work, apart from looping audio.  Maybe it's too complicated but I didn't find shorter version.  My video is 50fps.

```
ffmpeg -i Input40s.mp4 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]split=3[v0][v1][v2]; \
    [v0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=1699,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[0v]; \
    [v1]trim=start_frame=1700:end_frame=1701,loop=1500:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[1v]; \
    [v2]trim=start_frame=1802:end_frame=2000,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[2v]; \  
    [0:a]asplit=3[a1][a2][a3]; \
    [a0]atrim=0:32,asetpts=N/SR/TB[0a]; \
    [a1]atrim=30:32,asetpts=N/SR/TB[1a]; \
    [a2]atrim=32:40,asetpts=N/SR/TB[2a]; \
    [0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" \
    -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 4M  -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
    Out70s.mp4
```

It splits properly and concat together, but audio in this 30s freeze is only 2s, and AFAIK `loop` or `-stream_loop` doesn't go together with atrim

Comment: is it as simple as a missing `aloop` on the `[a1]` chain?

Comment: @kesh I've checked and actually found aloop option on french ffmpeg site, added aloop=15:2:30; but no luck